# Warmup scripts?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013

In SharePoint 2013 we used [SPWarmUp](http://spwarmup.codeplex.com/) to start our web applications each morning. We've now got a new SharePoint 2013 installation in place and are looking for a better way to do this. Has anybody done this  with Powershell, or is there a better way of acomplishing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not rely on a crawl schedule for the relevant content sources ? I do this for nearly all my SharePoint installations, the crawler will hit all targeted sites, ensure search result freshness and will do the warm-up, all without custom scripts / tools...

Comment: Ah, awesome, I ddidn't realise that will warmup also

Comment: yupp, that's even more relevant in 2013 than it was in 2007 / 2010 now that they are so many things search based. Glad it helped. Thanks for your comment.